# Crossfilter/d3.js -can I show the fraction of records that have been selected via a crossfilter?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have some bar charts that leverage crossfilter to allow a user to dynamically filter the data set. When a user selects some portion of the data set, then the other bar charts show fewer records, as part of that data is getting filtered out.

I'd also like to have a stacked bar chart that shows the percent of all records that have been selected, vs. the percent of original records. So for example, pre-brush selection, the stacked bar chart would have just one rectangle at 100%. Then, after selecting some of the data, it could show one bar with 60% and another bar with 40%.

Is this possible? How would I go about implementing this type of solution either via d3.js + crossfilter, or dc.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a dimension `dim` that you don't filter on, then `dim.all().length / crossfilter.size()`.

If you are using the latest alpha of crossfilter2, you can just use `crossfilter.all().length / crossfilter.size()` without needing to define an additional dimension.